# Update $scope from inside callback in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I have this controller and I would like to update the `$scope.progress` from within the function callback. I tried using `$rootScope` and `$scope.apply()` but I can't get it to work.
Is there something I'm missing?

progressupdate is a variable returned by the event. 
the code is not exactly like this. I made it super simple here to show the structure.

```
app.controller('player', function($scope) {

    var show = function(url) {
        function(err, showOK) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                showOK.on('listening', function(){
                     $scope.progress = progressupdate;
                });
            }
        });
    }

    show(url);

});
```

Am I running that function incorrectly inside the controller?
Should I use something like this?

```
 $scope.show = function(url)...etc
```

Comment: Your example is syntactically incorrect.  Not sure if that's a bad copy/paste or the actual problem.

Comment: oops, some bad copypasta.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I don't see the `$apply` function on above script, and progressupdate. Try `$apply` after set, or set it inside `$apply` :

```
showOk.on('listening', function(){
   $scope.$apply(function(){
      $scope.progress = progressupdate;
   });
});
```

or

```
showOk.on('listening', function(){
   $scope.progress = progressupdate;
   $scope.$apply();
});
```

The first method is recommended.

Comment: I guess I'm pretty burned out cause I tried what you suggested before and couldn't get it to work! thanks!